# Plott progress of fitting / GridSearch etc

Tags: python, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory, sklearn-pandas, grid-search

I'm currently working on a showcase in Python. My manager wants me to show the whole code/process to our customers. Currently we are using public data to fit the model. When it comes to present the whole code to our customers we will run with customer data and fit the model live.

Since I'm doing a GridSearch in google colab the whole process will take several minutes.

This step is critical since it takes nearly 10 - 15 minutes: 
`gs_classificator = GridSearchCV(MNB_clf, parameters, n_jobs=-1)`

*Is there a way to plot the current progress of fitting like a loading bar or sth else?*

I'm sure this will take a few more moments to fit the modell but on the other hand it will make it a bit more transparent for audience.

I think there is no such function implemented in `sklearn.model_selection` but maybe someone knows how to modify the code.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: correct typo `n_jobs=1` to `n_jobs=-1`

Comment: Why `n_jobs=1` ? You can cut fitting times by 4/8 times, assuming you have enough RAM

Comment: You need to it manually.

Comment: @BlackBear thy. This was a typo. I've edited my post.